# Avoiding inter-module dependencies, avoiding event as a global variable - What should be given more importance? why?

Tags: architecture, embedded, rtos, firmware

**Approach 1** ->
*module A*
a.c

```
#include <os_wrapper.h>
event* a;
createEventFlag(a); - RTOS function
```

*OS wrapper*
os_wrapper.h

```
extern event* a;
```

*module B*
b.c

```
#include <os_wrapper.h>
.
.
postEventFlag(a);
```

**Approach 2** ->
*module A*
a.c

```
#include <os_wrapper.h>
static event* a;
createEventFlag(a); - RTOS function

eventFlagPostWrapper(); - user defined wrapper function
```

a.h

```
void eventFlagPostWrapper(void);
```

*module B*
b.c

```
#include <os_wrapper.h>
#include <a.h>

.
.
eventFlagPostWrapper();
```

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches have an inter-module dependency.  Approach 1 has both modules dependent on `a` while Approach 2 the dependency is `eventFlagPostWrapper`.  So neither avoids inter-module dependency, so your best approach then is the one that avoids the global variable, since the coupling is the same, but the safety improved.

You might consider Jack Ganssle's [A Pox on Globals](https://www.embedded.com/a-pox-on-globals/) which directly addresses this issue.

Comment: Thanks. Edited the question a bit, to depict the scenario faced by me better. However, I think the shared link will help me.

Comment: If you mentioned about which definition to take, corrected it.